# MYSQL - conversions to money

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a database that has financial transactions (eg 105.30) stored in a longtext datatype. I can not change the schema, and it is mariadb 10.0.38

I chose decimal(13,2) for my casting, but when I aggregate on one of the columns, I do get some inaccuracies. What should I do to get the numbers spot on?

eg
SELECT Country, SUM(CAST(mycolumn AS DECIMAL(13,2)))
GROUP BY Country

Comment: I've tried to emulate your problem on 10.4.8-MariaDB and couldn't. Maybe you could put together a fiddle and give an example of where your numbers are not "spot on"?

Comment: You probably have commas for separating thousands, millions etc. Before casting, you will need to use `REPLACE(mycolumn, ',', '')`

Comment: What is the largest number?  What value has the most decimal places?

Comment: As for "can't change" -- Why?

Comment: I can't change the schema because it is a third party schema - in this case, Woocommerce for Wordpress.